# Why Recyclerview not Scrolls when its height is taken match parent in below xml?

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#FFF"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete_places"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:drawablePadding="9dp"
            android:hint="@string/autocomplete_hint"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="9dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cross"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_clear"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_id"
        android:id="@+id/pick_position_layout_id"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:background="@color/window_background"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            android:elevation="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_gps"
                    android:tint="@color/common_action_bar_splitter"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="Use My Location"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerViewID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pick_position_layout_id"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_id"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Above is my complete xml file.My problem is that when in below Recyclerview I make height wrap_content it scrolls but when made match_parent it does not scroll can you tell me the reason?

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerViewID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pick_position_layout_id"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

But this Recyclerview works with both match_parent and wrap_content.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_id"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Can you tell me the reason?
Thanks in advance :)